# SearchKit - using custom logic instead of plain path

Tags: reactjs, searchkit

We use searchKit client of @searchkit/client in our react application

The search kit config looks like this:

```
export const searchkitConfig = (authHeaders) => {
const config = {
    host: '/api/<URL>/v1/audit',
    index: 'in_app_audit',
    connectionOptions: {
    headers: authHeaders,
    },
    hits: {
    fields: ['category', 'type', 'level', 'message', 'user_email', 'timestamp'],
    },
    sortOptions: [
    {
        id: 'timestamp.desc', label: 'Time', field: [{ timestamp: 'desc' }], defaultOption: true,
    },
…
```

I need to wrap are request with an async TokenRequest component. the TokenRequest handles all the token logic, and if the request fails, it sends a request for a new token, then calls the original request again. Here is an example of how we do it in other places in the code:

```
export async function createAccount(data, messages) {
  return tokenRequest({
  path: 'asset-service/v1/accounts', method: 'POST', data, messages,
});
```

}

In general, I could use [transporter](https://v3.searchkit.co/docs/core/reference/searchkit-sdk#building-your-own) to add complicated logic, but we don’t do the API request directly with the Searchkit.
(Example of using Searchkit directly with transporter:

```
const response = await Searchkit(skConfig, transporter).execute({
  hits: {
    from: 0,
    size: 10,
  }});
```

instead the code uses  useSearchkit from @searchkit/client, and does these requests with this code:

```
const api = useSearchkit();
api.search();
```

Comment: You can pass a function to searchkit headers instead I believe. Which means if you need to pass some token, you can find the token from some storage engine every time you need to.  Or do the tokenRequest call there, before the request has been made.